# How can I get my domain joined Windows 10 computer to communicate with a fresh Azure ADDS using secure LDAPS?

Tags: ldap

A domain joined laptop to a fresh Azure ADDS doesn't seem to be communicating or picking up any of the group policy or password changes using the secure LDAPS.

The Microsoft documentation that I was provided had this whole section about secure LDAP and how it can work over the internet, and I was able to get it to work with the tool that they suggested, the LDP program. However, I was never able to get a Windows 10 physical computer or virtual machine to communicate with the domain controller without using a VPN client.

Does Windows 10 use secure LDAP over the internet? I'm unable to find a straight answer anywhere.

Thanks!